# Django upgrade to 1.8 issue - Argparse option callback is not supported

Tags: django

I have been trying to move to django 1.8 and currently stuck with this issue:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 247, in add_arguments
(attr, value))
AssertionError: argparse option callback=<function _log at 0x114fd1c80> is not supported
```

Looked around, could not find a solution. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

I hit this issue when i try to run:

```
python manage.py test
```

Comment: Do you have the `TEST_RUNNER` settings set ?

Comment: Yes, TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'